# Rails 5 - Ransack query with Simple Form grouping with OR combinator

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, ransack

In my application I have a `JobAd` model. With several attributes, and I am using Ransack, with Simple Form to query this model.
For some attributes, like `:title`, `:category`, I want to use the default combinator `AND`, but for a specific group of attributes I want to use `OR` combinator. This attributes are:

- onsite_job (type boolean)
- full_remote (type boolean)
- partial_remote (type boolean)

So far I was able to make the form work with the `AND` combinator. But I am not able to create the group for those fields. How can I achieve this, using Ransack with Simple Form builder.

**In my view I have the following:**

```rb
= search_form_for @q, url: backoffice_person_offer_suggestions_path(@person), remote: true, wrapper: :default20, builder: SimpleForm::FormBuilder, html: { method: :get } do |f|

  = f.input :category_id_in, as: :select, collection: -> { Category.all },label: 'Category', input_html: { class: 'ld-select-button', multiple: true }
  = f.input :experience_min_eq, collection: ProfileForm::EXPERIENCE_YEARS, label: 'Minimum Experience Years', input_html: { class: 'ld-select-button' }, include_blank: 'Any'

/ [...some other fields..]

  = f.input :onsite_job_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Onsite', input_html: { include_hidden: false }
  = f.input :full_remote_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Fully remote', input_html: { include_hidden: false }
  = f.input :partial_remote_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Partially remote', input_html: { include_hidden: false }

/ [...some other fields..]

  = f.submit value: 'Search', class:'ld-button ld-blue-button ld-medium-button'
```

How can I group those attributes under a `OR` combinator?

---

- Ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 5.2.5
- PostgreSQL 10.18
- Ransack 2.3.2
- Simple Form 5.0.2

---

#### Update

If I remove Simple Form from my project, I am able to generate the appropriate input tag with with the nested group:

```rb
f.grouping_fields do |g|
  g.check_box :onsite_job_true
end
```

Output:

```html
<input name="q[g][0][onsite_job_true]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="q[g][0][onsite_job_true]" id="q_g_0_onsite_job_true">
```

But when I add Simple Form, if I try code like: `f.input_field :grouping_fields` or `f.input :grouping_fields`

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `grouping_fields' for Ransack::Search<class: JobAd, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Which seems Simple Form is sending the `:grouping_fields` to the Ransack instance`@q`.

Comment: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#advanced-mode, https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/helpers/form_builder.rb, and https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo might help. Mixing and/or groups is logically complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the FormHelper builder was set  to `builder: SimpleForm::FormBuilder`.

That's why I was not able to do `f.grouping_fields`

After removing the `builder: SimpleForm::FormBuilder`, I was able to do:

```rb
= f.grouping_fields do |g|
  = g.input :m, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: 'or' }
  = g.input :onsite_job_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Onsite', input_html: { include_hidden: false }
  = g.input :full_remote_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Fully remote', input_html: { include_hidden: false }
  = g.input :partial_remote_true, as: :ld_boolean, label: 'Partially remote', input_html: { include_hidden: false }
```

Which generated the appropriate grouping with the `OR` combinator.